# Why my bash script does not work properly?

Tags: arrays, bash, grep

I wrote the following bash script for resizing an image (icon.png) using file config.xml, which contains necessary image sizes and links for saving resized files.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
function help {
  echo "For running the program, please write"
  echo "1) config.xml file's location containing image sizes and links for saving resized images;"
  echo "2) a name of an image to be resized."
}

function resize {
  array=()
  while read -r line
  do
    case $line in *icon*) array+=("$line");; esac
  done < $1
  for ((a=0; a < ${#array[*]}; a++))
  do
    echo "$a: ${array[$a]}"
    imagesize=$(echo "$a: ${array[$a]}" | grep "<icon"| grep -E -o "height=\"(\d+)" | grep -E -o "\d+")
    imagelink=$(echo "$a: ${array[$a]}" | grep "<icon"| grep -E -o "[^\"\'=[:space:]]+\.(jpe?g|png|gif)")
    echo $2 -resize $imagesizex$imagesize! ../../$imagelink
  done
  echo "Resizement has been executed"
}

if [ ! -f "$1" ] || [ ! -f "$2" ]
then
  help
else
  resize
fi
```

I get the following error: "line 9: $1: ambiguous redirect"

If I check the array, I get the following output:

```
<icon height="36" width="36" density="ldpi" src="res/icon/android/ldpi.png"/>.
```

I get only one line instead of a list of lines.

Could you please help me to make the code work correctly? Also, I would like to know why the script isn't correct.

Comment: share the error that you facing.

Comment: I get the following error: "line 9: $1: ambiguous redirect"

Comment: change call function resize to "resize $1 $2"

Comment: Inside a function $1 means the first parameter passed to the function, not to the script